# Add object in array just if the object.id doesn't match any ids in the array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of objects and I want to add another object just if the attribute `object.id` doesn't match any of the ids of the objects I have in the array.

I know I can go through the array and checking one buy one, but is there any easier way of doing so in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array << foo unless array.any? { |e| e.id == foo.id }
```

or

```
array << foo unless array.map(&:id).include?(foo.id)
```

Comment: Good, but better to use `object_id`. The number of objects that override `id` is probably huge, and it might even be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I like the @Mori answer but if possible you should think if a Hash does not make more sense in you problem. Will you need to fetch objectss from your array based on id? If so you should make it an hash.

And then you would do

`list[a.id] = a if list[a.id].nil?`

Comment: +1. I used this approach recently - *but* I was using a language which doesn't have `include?` (I was programming an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script).